# What does component mean in classification of 1 manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

In classifying 1 manifolds one has the following lemma

> Let $f:I \rightarrow M $ and $g: J \rightarrow M$ be parametrizations by arc-length. Then $f(I) \cap g(J) $ has at most two components.

What does *components* mean here?
Also, I am reading Milnor's Topology from the differentiable viewpoint. He uses many concepts without defining and the reader is expected to know them already. Which is a good reference wherein I can find most of them?

Comment: Most likely (path) connected components?

Comment: You can find these things in an ordinary topology book. I like Munkres "Topology".